# How sine and cosine can be used to describe 2d-vector coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Recently, I have seen this notation:
$\vec{a}=
l·\begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(270) \\
    \sin(270) \\
    \end{pmatrix}=
l·\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Where the coordinates of the vector are expressed with trigonometric functions, and then scaled to the proper length afterwards. I don't get how the trigonometric function can be used as coordinates for the vector. I hope you can explain this for me.

I drew a sketch of the situation:
[Vector sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEUG4.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors have real numbers as their coordinates. Here $\cos(270)$ and $\sin(270)$ are names of two particular real numbers. We can get other names for this numbers if we evaluate $\cos(270)$ and $\sin(270)$. This names would be $0$ and $-1$ respectively.

Sometimes functions are used to name things.

You can think of $\cos(270)$ as "that real number which is cosine of 270". The same applies to $\sin(270)$.

So your vector becomes

$$\vec{a}=
l·\begin{pmatrix}
    \text{"that real number which is cosine of 270"} \\
    \text{"that real number which is sine of 270"} \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Multiplication by $l$ multiplyes both coordinates and you get an effect of 
scaling.

Added:

Why are there sine and cosine?

The pair $(cos(x), sin(x))$ is there to select some point on a unit circle.
A vector with such coordinates will have length $1$ and, as you can imagine, can point to some direction.
Then this vector is scaled by $l$ to get desired length without changing its orientation.

Comment: Okay, explains it a bit better. As I commented at another answer, is the explanation something like: By inserting my angle into the cosine function, I get the according value on the x-axis, which I can then scale by the length of the vector. The same goes for the sine function, where I just get the according value on the y-axis instead?

Comment: yes, here you can think of it that way.

Comment: @BleuDylan added some information on why sine and cosine are used there.

Comment: Perfect. The extra explanation was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use trigonometric function can be useful to parametrize a line through the origin and with slope $\theta$ with respect to $x$ axis that is

$$\vec{a}=
l·\begin{pmatrix}
    \cos \theta \\
    \sin \theta \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

with $l\in \mathbb{R}$ parameter.

Note that in your example it should be

$$\vec{a}=
l·\begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(270) \\
    \sin(270) \\
    \end{pmatrix}=
l·\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    \color{red}{-1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You are absolutely right about -1 instead of -1.2. Anyways, correct me if I'm wrong: By inserting my angle into the cosine function, I get the according value on the x-axis, which I can then scale by the length of the vector. The same goes for the sine function, where I just get the according value on the y-axis instead?